# Genymotion emulator get stuck after adb reboot

Tags: android, genymotion

My genymotion emulator gets stuck every time when I run "adb reboot" in the command line.

I have found that the versions of adb inside the android sdk and adb inside genymotion tools folder are different; Sdk adb version is 1.0.36 and genymotion adb version is 1.0.32.

Can anyone please guide me to get rid of this problem. Help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Update genymotion?

Comment: Genymotion is already updated. Version of my genymotion is 2.7.2. And it is the latest one available.